# Align responsive div to the right within container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have one parent div and two child divs. My aim is to center one div and align the other div to the right and make both **responsive**.

I can't seem to find the conventional way to do align the second one to the right within this type of setup:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="middle">Centered to middle</div>

    <div id="right">I want to be to the right</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#middle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:150px;
    height:300px;
}

#right {
    max-width:150px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoktptuc/). How do we crack this puzzle?

Comment: Well that depends entirely on how you want the width distributed. Currently there's no indication of that. How do you imagine center should be positioned at different times?

Comment: Do you have a picture? `float:right` on the right hand div keeps it right and when you say responsive, they are 150px max width? what would they shrink on? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the 150px in size is only an example for the jsfiddle, click the link for demonstration.

Comment: I did click the link, it's a fiddle and they are set at 150px max - if that's not the case then please change your code and explain the problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Make it `inline-block`, otherwise the second `div` would always be on the second line
2. Reduce their `width` in percentage, making it `33%`
3. Remove `max-width`

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:middle;
}
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
#middle {
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left:40%;
    height:300px;
}

#right {
    background:yellow;
    width:33%;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
    <div id="middle">Centered to middle</div>
    
    <div id="right">I want to to be to the right</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is a problem. My middle div must be a fixed width. Please see this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/aoktptuc/1/ --- is there any way around this with a fixed div for middle one?

Comment: @Hen with fixed width of the middle div, the right one would drop on the another line when the width of the window is small, do you realize it?

Comment: @nicael Of course. I am adding display:none; to the right div when the screen size gets too small. So do you by any chance have a solution to the current problem?

Comment: While the right div is aligned to the right, it isn't actually aligned to the right of the middle div, but to the right of the screen. You know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Added a pseudo element as left column, so the layout becomes to [left] + [middle] + [right] and set `table` for the parent and `table-cell` for the children.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L4gn1t6x/)**

```css
#container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#container:before, #middle, #right {
    display: table-cell;
}
#container:before {
    content:"";
}
#middle {
    background: aqua;
    width: 50%;
}
#right {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="middle">Centered to middle</div>
    <div id="right">I want to to be to the right</div>
</div>
```

There is another approach by using `flexbox`, can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29322896/483779)**.

Comment: Cheers, very interesting approach. What about compatibility? Is this approach conventional and should work cross browser?

Comment: I believe it works on all modern browser, since there is nothing fancy.

Comment: Ah, found a problem. The right div is not responsive. It has a max-width but the width is set, I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aoktptuc/3/ the added css code is only to make inline-block work on ie7.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I revised the answer, and realized that I also answered it on the other post, anyway it's a different approach, check it out :)