# Make right div within container responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 divs in a container, one in the center and one to the right. I want the width of the right div to be **responsive**. Currently, only the `max-width` on the centered one works.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoktptuc/4/).

How do I make the right div responsive too?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="middle">Centered</div>

    <div id="right">Make me responsive</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#middle {
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#right {
    background:yellow;
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: absolute;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: what reaction do you expect from two responsive  adjacent divs?!

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Logically, the right div should "shrink" until the screen hits the centered div. Shrink the screen in the fiddle for a demonstration of this.

Comment: @nima Not sure I understand your question. The middle div should be set to max-width:300px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use [**`flexbox`**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). And add a pseudo element for left column, in order to make the middle one in the center with your existing markup.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vkggyuv/)**

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
}
#container:before, #middle, #right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}
#container:before {
    content:"";
}
#middle {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="middle">Centered</div>
    <div id="right">Responsive</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want by doing something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoktptuc/9/)
Only problem is your middle div has to have a fixed width but using media queries you can forget about that. Keep in mind that [calc browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) could be better (although there are [polyfills](https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill)).

```
#middle {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 340px;
    background: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: calc(50% - 170px);
    background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 340px) {
    #middle {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 340px;
    }
    #right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**BEFORE EDIT**

`max-width` is not working on elements where `position` is set to `absolute`.

What exactly do you want do accomplish with `absolute` and also, what kind of layout do you want to get in the end?

Answer (score 0):

remove the max-width from right div. also you have to set a percent less than 100% but totally 100% to make sense to responsive divs:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#middle {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#right {
  background: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  #right {
    display: none;
  }
  #middle {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="middle">Centered</div>

  <div id="right">Make me responsive</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is a problem. My aim is to fill the whole screen. So centered div covers lets say 700px width and the right div covers 50% of what's remaining (because we have the left space empty). So the right div should always reach to the end of the screen, but not overlaps it. You solution does not work with this, right?